# How to 'Connection Pool in couchbase db' in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I'm creating a new API server (use Nodejs and Couchbase db) and i want to connect pool to couchbase db, how do it? thanks advance!

Comment: I guess all the nosql database manages connection pool automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [nano](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano) for configuring the same.

This is taken straight out of the docs -

> **Pool size and open sockets**
>
> A very important configuration parameter if you have a high traffic
>   website and are using nano is setting up the pool.size. By default,
>   the Node.js HTTP global agent (client) has a certain size of active
>   connections that can run simultaneously, while others are kept in a
>   queue. Pooling can be disabled by setting the agent property in
>   requestDefaults to false, or adjust the global pool size using:
>
> `http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 20;`
>
> You can also increase the size in your calling context using
>   requestDefaults if this is problematic. Refer to the request
>   documentation and examples for further clarification.